# Does interest income on a foreign bank account (or a high balance thereof) require you to file taxes if below the Personal Filing Threshold?

Tags: united-states, taxes, bank-account

If a US person (either resident alien, permanent resident, or citizen) in a given year, claimed as a dependent on a US citizen's return, had a salary of less than $1500, domestic interest income/dividends/capital gains of less than $300, and passive interest income on a foreign bank account of less than $200, does he/she have to file taxes (in any of the years of the last decade)  or does the *Personal Filing Threshold* apply?

Further, do the requirements of Form 8938 force such an individual to file federal taxes if the balance of the foreign bank account is sufficiently high?

I would appreciate an answer that answers the two questions separately because the balance might have been below the 8938 threshold in certain years.

Comment: By US person, do you mean a US citizen or a US resident for tax purposes (not necessarily the same as a US resident as per visa status)? What about the someone else on whose return you are being claimed as a dependent?

Comment: I edited my answer. The individual who claimed the person of interest was a US citizen and the person of interest went through all of the different US person classifications listed through the years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're considering OVDP - you should pose this question to your attorney and not relay on laymen on Internet forums.

*Personally* I would suggest filing tax return in this case regardless of the personal threshold, because part of the return is the stupid checkbox that you must click to notify the IRS that you have these accounts is on schedule B, and unless you file and its checked, it is considered unchecked.

If your balances high enough to require form 8938 than you **must** file, and the statute of limitations clock for that year doesn't start ticking until you do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't make enough dividends/interest  for Schedule B, so I'm not sure that "it is considered unchecked." The reason I asked this question is to see if I could do the paperwork myself instead of paying legal fees that eat up my entire salary.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn If it is not checked - of course its unchecked. Did you check it? No, you didn't, because you didn't file a return - but who cares. What exactly are you talking about when you're saying that you could do the paperwork yourself - OVDP? You want to do OVDP yourself? Don't be an idiot.

Comment: But if it is unchecked (if I'm below the Schedule B requirement) then I won't check it either when I file a delinquent return (because the delinquent return won't have a Schedule B). Regarding your last comment, are you implying that it is a bad idea to go through the OVDP w/o representation?

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn I don't understand why would you not check it. Did you have a foreign account at that year? From your question it seems that you have. Why would you not check it? Yes, I'm implying that going through OVDP w/o representation is a financial suicide.

Comment: The checkbox is on Schedule B. If I'm below the $1500 (interest + dividends) Schedule B filing threshold, I wouldn't fill out Schedule B. If I'm below the Personal Filing Threshold, I wouldn't even file a 1040. Filing a delinquent return triggers 'failure to file' penalties. Regarding the second point: The OVDP seems straightforward enough. The uncertainty for me is limited to the question asked above. Two other people told me that hiring a lawyer was, in fact, the "financial suicide," not the expected IRS penalties. Why do you believe that representation is important?

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn I don't think you understood what I'm saying. The fact that you're under the reporting threshold for income taxes doesn't mean you're allowed not to report your foreign accounts. So if you have foreign accounts - you will have schedule B. Even if you have no interest or dividends at all. Because there's a checkbox there that you **must** check. Is it clear enough? Re representation: You broke the law, and the punishment is severe, if not draconian. Do you really want to take your chances with admitting guilt without representation?

Comment: I see what you're saying. Thanks for your comments. Regarding OVDP: the penalties are flat, irrespective of how much guilt you admit. However, you make a good point if I decide to opt-out of the program and instead want to expose myself to a civil audit. In that case, penalties can range from $0 to MORE THAN the one-size-fits-it-all OVDP fines - all depending on how the examiner feels about your case.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn penalties are not flat and can reach magnitude of hundreds of thousands, in in some cases were even millions. BTW: from what I read (it was reported by the IRS actually) people who opted out paid less in penalties on average than those who didn't.

Comment: The fine is 27.5% of the highest aggregate balance whether you hire the Yale-top-of-the-class big-shot in Manhattan or the ignorant swamp-dweller with a shady law certificate from Tampa (or DIY), whether you are a money-laundering, tax-evading financial schemer or an expat student who didn't bother with obscure tax forms. That's of course only if you don't qualify for the 5% or 15% categories. You are right with respect to the opt-out: The average penalty has been around $16k, but there is a bias towards benign actors.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn You're mistaken. In one recent very famous case some very well lawyered up person who evaded taxes on balances well over 1 *billion* dollars paid about 50 *million* dollars fine. That's 5% in my book. If you want to pay the maximum possible - that's your money, of course. I just think its not wise.

Comment: Unless this person qualified for the 5% OVDP fine (unlikely), he must have been penalized outside the OVDP. I have to agree with you that representation is appropriate in a moderately big case without the safety net of the OVDP. **Within the OVDP**, however, examiners have no discretion for penalty abatement and I still stand by my previous comment.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn lets start with that representation will help you decide whether you even want it. Most likely - you *don't* want OVDP. I'm sorry, I just cannot understand why a sane person would willingly submit like that without even wanting to ask for a professional advice.